# Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm/sentry-cli

Tags: node.js, linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I am trying to Host my frontend part in AWS using EC2 instance.

*As there are similar questions but none of them helped me!!*

**While Building i am using some linux commands**

`npm i --legacy-peer-deps`

**But i encountering with error like -**

`npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/root/.npm/sentry-cli'`

Is this correct way to do this or please suggest me other method!!!

Comment: What operating system user are you?  It sounds like you're trying to build this as the `root` user.  That's generally not best practice.

Comment: @stdunbar regardless whether i am root user or not but it still gives the same error

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [ubuntu.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: @stdunbar While it may not be best practice, root shouldn't get permission errors.